# How should I manage memory for C block feature? (Apple extension)

Tags: c, memory-management, block

Apple introduced a closure in C as name of 'block'.
Should I manage memory for the blocks? If so, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like variables with function scope in plain C, blocks literals in functions have automatic storage duration. When you think of a block literal as a pointer type you see what can go wrong: When you return a block from a function you are returning a pointer to local memory, which is no longer valid.

The solution is to use the `Block_copy()` function whenever you want to return a block and the `Block_release()` when you no longer need it.

More information in [this tutorial](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#cblocks) that has a separate section on blocks in C.